# What is a 'Turn and Burn'?

Tags: halo-4

I was attacking the enemy base in a banshee, and the game announced "Turn and Burn". It doesn't show up as a medal on Waypoint. What is it?

Comment: My google-fu has been surprisingly week on this.  As best I can tell it's a term for a type of kill in Halo, but people seem to talk about it without exactly saying what it is.  I've gotten it a few times, so I'm very curious as well.

Comment: @CaulynDarr - Same here, my Google-fu is normally very strong. I was quite surprised to not find an answer!

Comment: I'm expecting it to be something like killing someone with the thrusters on the back, but I don't own the game and no previous Halo had any mechanics that allowed vehicle thrusters to cause damage so I'm probably wrong.

Comment: @MrSmooth - That would be cool, but you're correct, the thrusters don't cause any damage. I do know for certain that it doesn't have anything to do with stunts, as I hadn't figured out how to do stunts yet at that point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a video recorded in which the announcer says "Turn and Burn".  I'm still trying to figure out if there is [a way for me to link said video from my fileshare](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/92947/how-do-i-access-my-fileshare-outside-the-game), so bear with me there.

As for my analysis, I believe that it means: ***You are about to lose.***  This is somewhat supported by the origin of the phrase, [as others have pointed out](https://forums.halowaypoint.com/yaf_postsm1749216_What-Does--Turn-and-Burn--mean.aspx).

In the circumstances within my video, all members of my team hear the announcement, and my team is losing.  The game type was Dominion.  Immediately after the "Turn and Burn" announcement the announcer says "The Enemy has almost won".  There is a slight delay, but as I listen to it (over and over) it sounds intended to be one phrase: "Turn and Burn... the Enemy has almost won."  When I switch perspectives to enemy team members, I also noticed that they do not hear the announcement.  I believe all of this supports my hypothesis that this is a "You are about to lose" announcement.

Comment: That does sound likely. I'll have to pay more attention to the next one and see if it's followed by "The enemy has almost won."

Comment: Also, in the previous games, while you could access your pictures from anywhere, you could only render videos by paying for it.

Comment: @SaintWacko rendering outside of the game costed money, yes - but I could still share videos for queued download and in game rendering. "Fileshare" tends to imply that I can share files - not clear how I can do that right now.

Comment: Oh, okay, I thought you wanted to link it for viewing from a web browser.

Comment: Yep, that's definitely it! I lost a couple games tonight, and both times it was said.