# How do I access my fileshare outside the game?

Tags: halo-4

Previous installments of the Halo series let you access your fileshare outside the game to queue downloads, and share files.  I can't seem to figure out how to do this for Halo 4.  I'm most interested in sharing files with others, ideally something linkable.  How do I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Feb 2013 Update: In the [27/2/13 Halo Bulletin](http://blogs.halowaypoint.com/Headlines/post/2013/02/27/The-Halo-Bulletin-22713.aspx) it was announced that the [Halo 4 File Browser](http://www.halowaypoint.com/en-us/games/halo4/filebrowser) is now online. There is a [Waypoint Blog](http://blogs.halowaypoint.com/post/2013/02/27/Halo-4-File-Browser-Available-on-Waypoint-Web.aspx) blog post detaling its features and how to use it.

---

The answer, currently, is "You Don't" however after looking around on the Waypoint forums "The Little Moa" says,

> [File share support for Halo 4 will be added next month on the
>   website.](https://forums.halowaypoint.com/yaf_postsm1697705_Halo-4-File-Share.aspx#post1697705)

so sometime in December, I would think.

---

EDIT, 19th December: I spotted a bit in the [12/12/12 Halo Bulletin](http://halo.bungie.org/halobulletins/79) where it says

> We expect both Search and web access to come online in early 2013, and
>   we'll provide another update in January. Again, we apologize for the
>   delay, and we know this is painful for many of you.

So, keep waiting.

Comment: Thanks for the source.  I'm not sure "The Little Moa" is super credible, but it's the best source I've seen so far on the subject, and I appreciate the research.

Comment: Sorry, I was trying to find what role the user had in the forum, be it high-ranking forum user, 343 or Waypoint staff but I coudln't see it.

Answer (score 2):

The official site for Halo 4 has become [Halo Waypoint](http://www.halowaypoint.com).
 If you cannot access your fileshare from there, then I am sure it is not possible to access it remotely.
This might not have been the answer you wanted to read, but that's how it stands.

Comment: I'm used to disappointment, don't worry. You say "if" though.. do you have any info about it officially not being supported on Waypoint?

Comment: @EBongo I have yet to log in on the site, but it is the official site for Halo 4 and thus the only way it could be possible. It even has an xbox.com domain (halo.xbox.com), so you can trust it being the official site.